# Cannot load JS dynamically (without jQuery)

Tags: javascript, html, code-injection

I use this code, but javascript is not loading.

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var script = document.createElement('script');
var prefix = this.is_current_https ? "https://" : "http://";
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.onload = fnCustomHandler;
script.src = prefix + 'apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
head.appendChild(script);
```

not even listening to `script.onreadystatechange` is generating any output.

When I debug `console.log(script)` I see whole element created properly, but referenced script is not loaded.

I tried too `head.appendChild(script.cloneNode(true));`

**Notes**

- after document.onload
- in google chrome
- no errors in console

**Notes 2**

Discovered on @`john_doe` comment, **script code gets injected into page** (into html->head), **but not loaded** (as seen in Networking tab). What can cause this?

Comment: What error is shown in the console?

Comment: Is the request listed in the Network tab?

Comment: @john_doe good point, it is visible in html>head>script element (they get injected) but they are not loaded, I can't see them in Network tab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says that it loads an object:

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var script = document.createElement('script');
var prefix = this.is_current_https ? "https://" : "http://";
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.onload = function () {
    alert('typeof window.gapi.plusone === ' + typeof window.gapi.plusone); // this
};
script.src = prefix + 'apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
head.appendChild(script);
```

Comment: If you can access http://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js then there must be with your environment (app / browser). As you see, it should work: http://jsfiddle.net/Nss4H/

Comment: Yes, I see. My code is triggered in onload from google chrome extension. `setTimeout` doesn't work too

Comment: Sorry, I debugged it again, and realized that what is causing problems is Adblock google chrome extension. I will create another question directly pointed to that fact.

Comment: Same here. I had the disconnect plugin stopping it

Answer (score 1):

I tried it and the error is that `fnCustomHandler` is undefinded, if i take that line of it loads perfectly.

EDIT - i tried

```
var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
var script = document.createElement('script');
var prefix = this.is_current_https ? "https://" : "http://";
script.type = 'text/javascript';
script.onload = function(){
alert('hi');
};
script.src = prefix + 'apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
head.appendChild(script);
```

and it works ok so there must be a problem in your function

Comment: `fnCustomHandler` is what he uses to listen to the script when it is loaded

Comment: yes, its sample name of handler function. but that function is not triggered at all

Comment: @MarekSebera i edited my answer, trying a sample function and i gets triggered both in firefox and chrome

Comment: @NicolaPeluchetti In what part of my function is problem? I tried logging `document.readyState` and it says `ready`